# Uninstall BuyNSave extension permanently

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, uninstall

How do I find out what program keeps installing BuyNSave extension in Google Chrome? I removed all extensions from Chrome, uninstalled all suspicious applications, but still, BuyNSave appears after every reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some kind of Adware Remover to remove Adwares and PUP (Potentially Unwanted Programs).
I personally use [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/).